# How to replace a line in a file through jtextfield?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, persistence

This is a program that allows the user to search for an item and then the program splits the items and stores them in 4 different `textfields`. However, below is a method for updating the retrieved items back to the file. The problem is whenever the user clicks on the update button, the line does update successfully, but the other lines in the file are deleted!

I am using an `arraylist` to store the searched item and also temporary file to write the item and then renaming it.

```
file.txt

ramal hotel1  10 uk

bren  hotel2  20 france

gil   hotel3  30 china
```

---

```
//Update to file
button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

    try {

    String stringSearch = textfield1.getText();

    File filetemp = File.createTempFile("TempFileName", ".tmp", new File("/"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filetemp));
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


    int linecount = 0;
              String line;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null){
    list.add(line);
    linecount++;


    int indexfound = line.indexOf(stringSearch);

    if (indexfound > -1) {

    String a = textfield1.getText();
    String b = textfield2.getText();
    String c = textfield3.getText();
    String d = textfield4.getText();




    String[] word = line.split("\t");
    String firstword = word[0];
    String secondword = word[1];
    String thirdword = word[2];
    String fourthword = word[3];




    writer.write(line.replace("\t", "\t").replace(firstword, b).replace(secondword, c).replace(thirdword, d));
    writer.flush();

    }

    writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
    bf.close();
    filetemp.renameTo(file);
    filetemp.deleteOnExit();


    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(filetemp).getChannel();
    FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
    dest.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());



    }catch (IOException e) {

    System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());

    }

}
});
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The call to `writer.write()` is only inside `if (indexfound > -1) {...}` but not in the `else`-path. Thus only lines are written which contain the search string. You also may remove `list` since you do not use it at all.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/408638/read-edit-and-write-to-file) on how to Read, write and update/edit a file in java.

Comment: Yes @Howard is correct. You are not writing only the string that are matching. So only one line is there. Use else block to write all the lines that does not match.

Comment: What do i write in the else statement? Can you show me one example please.

Comment: nevermind i did it. thanks for help.

else{
writer.write(line);
}

Answer (score 0):

You're saving only that data back to the file which contains the string you're searching for and you're ignoring the other lines.

Add this to your code just after the if block

```
else{
    writer.write(line);
    writer.flush();
}
```

just before the following line:

> writer.newLine();

So your code will look like this:

```
//Update to file
button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

    try {

    String stringSearch = textfield1.getText();

    File filetemp = File.createTempFile("TempFileName", ".tmp", new File("/"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filetemp));
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


    int linecount = 0;
              String line;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null){
    list.add(line);
    linecount++;


    int indexfound = line.indexOf(stringSearch);

    if (indexfound > -1) {

    String a = textfield1.getText();
    String b = textfield2.getText();
    String c = textfield3.getText();
    String d = textfield4.getText();




    String[] word = line.split("\t");
    String firstword = word[0];
    String secondword = word[1];
    String thirdword = word[2];
    String fourthword = word[3];




    writer.write(line.replace("\t", "\t").replace(firstword, b).replace(secondword, c).replace(thirdword, d));
    writer.flush();

    }
    else{
        writer.write(line);
        writer.flush();
    }
    writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
    bf.close();
    filetemp.renameTo(file);
    filetemp.deleteOnExit();


    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(filetemp).getChannel();
    FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
    dest.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());



    }catch (IOException e) {

    System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());

    }

}
});
```